# Spark dataframe filter

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

```
val df = sc.parallelize(Seq((1,"Emailab"), (2,"Phoneab"), (3, "Faxab"),(4,"Mail"),(5,"Other"),(6,"MSL12"),(7,"MSL"),(8,"HCP"),(9,"HCP12"))).toDF("c1","c2")

+---+-------+
| c1|     c2|
+---+-------+
|  1|Emailab|
|  2|Phoneab|
|  3|  Faxab|
|  4|   Mail|
|  5|  Other|
|  6|  MSL12|
|  7|    MSL|
|  8|    HCP|
|  9|  HCP12|
+---+-------+
```

I want to filter out records which have first 3 characters of column 'c2' either 'MSL' or 'HCP'.

So the output should be  like below.

```
+---+-------+
| c1|     c2|
+---+-------+
|  1|Emailab|
|  2|Phoneab|
|  3|  Faxab|
|  4|   Mail|
|  5|  Other|
+---+-------+
```

Can any one please help on this?

I knew that `df.filter($"c2".rlike("MSL"))` -- This is for selecting the records but how to exclude the records. ?

Version: Spark 1.6.2
Scala : 2.10

Comment: `val df1 = df.filter(not(df("c2")==="MSL")&&not(df("c2")==="HCP"))
` I am trying something like this.

Comment: val df1 = df.filter(not(df("c2").rlike("MSL"))&&not(df("c2").rlike("HCP")))

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
df.filter(not(
    substring(col("c2"), 0, 3).isin("MSL", "HCP"))
    )
```

Answer (score 33):

This works too. Concise and very similar to SQL.

```
df.filter("c2 not like 'MSL%' and c2 not like 'HCP%'").show
+---+-------+
| c1|     c2|
+---+-------+
|  1|Emailab|
|  2|Phoneab|
|  3|  Faxab|
|  4|   Mail|
|  5|  Other|
+---+-------+
```

Answer (score 7):

I used below to filter rows from dataframe and this worked form me.Spark 2.2

```
val spark = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)    
val data = spark.read.format("csv").
          option("header", "true").
          option("delimiter", "|").
          option("inferSchema", "true").
          load("D:\\test.csv")   


import  spark.implicits._
val filter=data.filter($"dept" === "IT" )
```

OR

```
val filter=data.filter($"dept" =!= "IT" )
```

Comment: for null filter use    val filter=data.filter($"dept".isNotNull )

Answer (score 0):

`val df1 = df.filter(not(df("c2").rlike("MSL"))&&not(df("c2").rlike("HCP")))`

This worked.

Comment: Using `rlike` in this way will also filter string like "OtherMSL", even if it does not start with the pattern you said.
Try to use `rlike("^MSL")` and `rlike("^HCP")` instead. 

Alternately you can also use the `.startsWith("MSL")` function.

Comment: You can use not equal like below example.                                                    df.filter(df("status") === "1" && df("SubType") =!= "Test")